# find the upper bound of $|f'(\alpha)|$

Tags: complex-analysis

find  $\max_{f} |f'(\alpha)|$ where  $f$ range over the class  of  analytics functions bounded  by $1$ in the unit disc  and  $\alpha$ is  a fixed  point of $|z|< 1$

**My attempt** : By using the  schwarz pick lemma . we have

$$
\left| \frac{f(z_1)-f(z_2)}{1- \overline{f(z_1)}f(z_2)} \right| \le \left| \frac{z_1-z_2}{1 - \overline{z_1}z_2} \right|,
$$

Put $z_1= z$  and $z_2 =\alpha$,then
$$
\left| \frac{f(z)-f(\alpha)}{1- \overline{f(z)}f(\alpha)} \right| \le \left| \frac{z-\alpha}{1 - \overline{z}\alpha} \right|,
$$

$$
\left| \frac{f(z)-f(\alpha)}{z- \alpha} \right| \le \left| \frac{1}{1 - \overline{z}\alpha} \right|,
$$

taking limit  $z \to \alpha$ on  both side then

$$
\lim_{z\to\alpha}\left| \frac{f(z)-f(\alpha)}{z- \alpha} \right| \le \lim_{z\to \alpha} \left| \frac{1}{1 - \overline{z}\alpha} \right|,
\implies |f'(\alpha) |\le | \frac{1}{1-\alpha^2}|$$

Therefore the  $\max_{f} |f'(\alpha)|$ is $| \frac{1}{1-\alpha^2}|$

Is it's correct ? yes/no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your calculation because $\lim_{z \to \alpha} \overline z \alpha = |\alpha|^2$ and not $\alpha^2$.

You have
$$
\left| \frac{f(z)-f(\alpha)}{z-\alpha} \right| 
\le \left| \frac{1- \overline{f(z)}f(\alpha)}{1 - \overline{z}\alpha} \right|
$$
and taking the limit $z \to \alpha$ gives
$$
 |f'(\alpha)| \le \frac{1-|f(\alpha)|^2}{1-|\alpha|^2} \le \frac{1}{1-|\alpha|^2}\, .
$$
(The left inequality is also known as part of the [Schwarz-Pick theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Schwarz%E2%80%93Pick_theorem).)

Equality holds for $f(z) = \frac{z-\alpha}{1-\overline\alpha z}$, so that the bound is sharp.